# Плохая индексация сайта на Яндекс

Tags: seo

Подскажите, по поводу контекстной рекламы, настроил компании, в GoogleAdwords сайт индексируется хорошо, на первой странице, а вот в ЯндексДирект другая история, настройки такие же, ключевые слова аналогичные, но индексирует на 2-4 странице, в чем может быть проблема, что его не пускает на 1 страницу поиска?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ставка - решение вашей проблемы. Поднимите ставку в Яндекс.Директ и "проиндексируетесь" хорошо.
Также прошу вас ознакомиться с тем, что такое 
Поисковая оптимизация (термин индексации относится именно к этой области), а также с тем, что такое Контекстная реклама, поскольку вы явно путаете их.

> в чем может быть проблема, что его не пускает на 1 страницу поиска?

Проблема в ставке. Ознакомьтесь с тем, Как работает аукцион Яндекс.Директ и с [Позициями показа на поиске](https://yandex.ru/support/direct/general/positions.html).
Вся информация есть в помощи Яндекс.Директ. Тоже самое изучите и по Google AdWords. С такими вопросами как у Вас я понимаю, что ваши деньги вылетят в трубу, поэтому не пренебрегайте хелпами.

А проблема заключается именно в том, что в Google AdWords хватает ставки для того, чтобы "проиндексироваться" на первой странице, а в Яндекс.Директ - нет.